# Pickling works in Python2 but not in Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pickle

My goal is to serialize a dictionary object to a specific file location, and read it back each time the program is run.  The following works in Python2.7, but throws an error in Python3.4.  What confuses me is that this works the first time an object is saved to disk, but not on subsequent executions.

The problem seems to be that in **setitem** an error is thrown that says that 'ConfigDict' object has no attribute '_config_file'.  Why does it not have a value any time except the first time I run the script??

```
import os
import pickle


class ConfigDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, config_name): # Name of a pickle file within configs directory
        self._config_directory = 'C:\\Users\\myfilepath\\configs'
        self._config_file = self._config_directory + '\\' + config_name + '.pickle'
        # If file does not exist, write a blank pickle file.
        if not os.path.isfile(self._config_file):
            with open(self._config_file, 'wb') as fh:
                pickle.dump({}, fh)
        # Read the pickle file from disk.
        with open(self._config_file, 'rb') as fh:
            pkl = pickle.load(fh)
            self.update(pkl)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        with open(self._config_file, 'wb') as fh:
            pickle.dump(self, fh)


cc = ConfigDict('DBConfig')
print()
print()
cc['config_val_1'] = '1'
cc['config_val_3'] = '3'
print(cc['config_val_3'])
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/filepath/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    cc = ConfigDict('DBConfig')
  File "C:/Users/filepath/test.py", line 16, in __init__
    pkl = pickle.load(fh)
  File "C:/Users/filepath/test.py", line 21, in __setitem__
    with open(self._config_file, 'wb') as fh:
AttributeError: 'ConfigDict' object has no attribute '_config_file'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full traceback and error message that you get when running with Python 3.4

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added.